# MySql on duplicate key update query works in terminal but not as a prepared statement in scala

Tags: java, mysql, scala, prepared-statement, on-duplicate-key

I am trying to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to avoid having to fail an insertion due to uniqueness constraints, then read the value into my program, check which fields don't have values and insert the new values then insert the updated row back into the DB.

This is what the prepared statement looks like.  If I use this exact same thing but with the ? replaced with values in the mysql console the query works fine.  It properly updates the values I want updated.

```
INSERT INTO business (business_id, name, normalized_name, industry, address, zip, city, county, state, country, website, email, phone, type, added, modified, source) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
industry = COALESCE(industry, VALUES(industry)), 
address = COALESCE(address, VALUES(address)), 
zip = COALESCE(zip, VALUES(zip)), 
city = COALESCE(city, VALUES(city)), 
county = COALESCE(county, VALUES(county)), 
state = COALESCE(state, VALUES(state)), 
country = COALESCE(country, VALUES(country)), 
website = COALESCE(website, VALUES(website)), 
email = COALESCE(email, VALUES(email)), 
phone = COALESCE(phone, VALUES(phone)), 
type = CASE  
        WHEN type = VALUES(type) THEN type 
        WHEN type = 'business' THEN type 
        WHEN VALUES(type) = 'lone' THEN type       
        WHEN VALUES(type) = 'business' THEN VALUES(type)  
        WHEN type = 'client' AND VALUES(type) = 'vendor' THEN  'business' 
        WHEN type = 'vendor' AND VALUES(type) = 'client' THEN  'business' 
    ELSE type
    END
```

But when I run it as a prepared statement in Scala no updates occur.  If there is no duplicate it inserts the row correctly.

Also is there a way to get this to return the id of the row that was updated?  I checked LAST_INSERT_ID() and it always points to the last auto incremented value.

Or am I way of base of how I should be doing this?  I have very little experience with MySql and I've spent the last few months on a Graph Database so things are different.

I'm using

Scala 2.11.2

MySql 5.6

Java 7

mysql-connector-java 5.1.34

Thanks for the help

Update:

```
var addBusinessQS = "INSERT INTO business (" + BUSINESS_FIELDS.mkString(", ") + ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) " +
                          "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "  +
                          "industry = COALESCE(industry, VALUES(industry)), " +
                          "address = COALESCE(address, VALUES(address)), " +
                          "zip = COALESCE(zip, VALUES(zip)), " +
                          "city = COALESCE(city, VALUES(city)), " +
                          "county = COALESCE(county, VALUES(county)), " +
                          "state = COALESCE(state, VALUES(state)), " +
                          "country = COALESCE(country, VALUES(country)), " +
                          "website = COALESCE(website, VALUES(website)), " +
                          "email = COALESCE(email, VALUES(email)), " +
                          "phone = COALESCE(phone, VALUES(phone)), " +
                          "type = CASE WHEN type = VALUES(type) THEN type " +
                                    "WHEN type = 'business' THEN type " +
                                    "WHEN VALUES(type) = 'lone' THEN type       " +
                                    "WHEN VALUES(type) = 'business' THEN VALUES(type)  " +
                                    "WHEN type = 'client' AND VALUES(type) = 'vendor' THEN  'business' " +
                                    "WHEN type = 'vendor' AND VALUES(type) = 'client' THEN  'business' " +
                                    "ELSE type " +
                                  "END "
  var addBusinessPS = masterConnection.prepareStatement(addBusinessQS)


def setOrNull(ps:PreparedStatement, index:Int, value:String, field:String)
  {
    if(value.trim.isEmpty)
      ps.setNull(index, 0)
    else
      ps.setString(index, truncateAndEscapeString(value, field))
  }

  def addBusiness(business:mutable.Map[String, String]) : Int = 
  {

   try{
      addBusinessPS.setNull(1, 0)
      setOrNull(addBusinessPS, 2, business("name"), "name")
      setOrNull(addBusinessPS, 3, business("name"), "normalized_name")
      setOrNull(addBusinessPS, 4, business("industry"), "industry")
      setOrNull(addBusinessPS, 5, business("address"), "address")
      addBusinessPS.setString(6, truncateAndEscapeString(business("zip"), "zip")) //This is not setOrNull because Unique constraint.
      setOrNull(addBusinessPS, 7, business("city"), "city")
      setOrNull(addBusinessPS, 8, business("county"), "county")
      setOrNull(addBusinessPS, 9, business("state"), "state")
      setOrNull(addBusinessPS, 10, business("country"), "country")
      setOrNull(addBusinessPS, 11, business("website"), "website")
      setOrNull(addBusinessPS, 12, business("email"), "email")
      setOrNull(addBusinessPS, 13, business("phone"), "phone")
      setOrNull(addBusinessPS, 14, business("type"), "type")
      addBusinessPS.setTimestamp(15, getCurrentTimeStamp)
      addBusinessPS.setNull(16, 0)
      setOrNull(addBusinessPS, 17, business("source"), "source")
      addBusinessPS.executeUpdate();

      var idResult = lastInsertedPS.executeQuery()
      idResult.next()
      return idResult.getString("LAST_INSERT_ID()").toInt
    } 
    catch 
    {
      case e:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException => { println("ConstraintError");return -1 }
      case e:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException => {println(e);System.exit(1);return -1}
    }

  }
```

Comment: Where is the code that is running this query?

Comment: Let me know if there is anything else needed to help.